# How to dynamically style ASP.net Listview LayoutTemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I'd like to be able to apply user selected colors and font sizes to the controls in my Listview's LayoutTemplate but can't use code blocks to adjust the style (codeblocks work great in the ItemTemplate). I've read some article that codeblocks don't work in the LayoutTemplate (and have first hand experience that they don't work). Does anyone have a method that will reliably allow me to adjust the styles? Should I use FindControl() in some event handler and add the styles there?

Comment: what code have you tried thus far..??

Comment: Use the CSS selectors instead like odd, even and ....

Comment: guys i think OP wants to alter cssclass using Eval from code behind.

Comment: Tried using codeblocks in aspx page. They never get called, which I found out is expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Anything customizable by the user, that isn't fixed at design time, would need to be applied to the ListView by finding the appropriate control and changing the CSS class unfortunately.  Alternatively, you could try dynamically writing out CSS that targets classes of the elements within the ListView, and change the colors purely with CSS.

**EDIT:** To dynamically output CSS, consider using a LiteralControl like:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
   var profile = GetProfile();

   LiteralControl ctl = new LiteralControl(@"
     <style>
         .UserStyleA 
         { 
            background-color: " + profile.BackgroundColor + @";
            color: " + profile.ForeColor + @";
     </style>");         
}
```

I believe then onload, you could append to the header, something like:

```
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(ctl);
```

However, in reading the documentation for the Page.header property, it has a great example of appending a stylesheet dynamically.  That seems to be exactly what you would need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.header.aspx

Comment: To be clear: Your suggesting that I modify the style by modifying the CSSClass attribute? That leads to the implication that I'd require a huge number of css class combinations to handle every possible size and color. Also: Where would I modify said attribute?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, target a name of a class via the CssClass attribute.  But No, not define every possible css class, but DYNAMICALLY GENERATE the CSS with the user defined styles.

Comment: I've never dynamically generated a css class. Any pointer or links on how to do this in ASP.net? And at what point do you apply these changes?

Comment: CSS is basically text in a sense; meaning from an ASp.NET standpoint, all you need to do is render a <style> tag with some inner styles.  You should be able to use a literal control to do this, I'll update the post above.

Answer (score 0):

You could try placing a user control inside the LayoutTemplate and moving the logic to said user control, something like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="CustomizableList" runat="server">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <custom:UserStyles runat="server" />

    <div class="user-list-layout">
      <asp:PlaceHolder ID="Item" />
    </div>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Something" runat="server" 
      Text='<%# Eval("Something") %>' 
      CssClass="user-list-something" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Follow the advice form Brian Mains' answer and only use CSS classes. Then in the UserStyles control you could dynamically generate some CSS that will be applied.

```
<style type="text/css" scoped>
  .user-list-layout {
    border-color: <%= Profile.FavoriteColor %>;
  }
  .user-list-something {
    font-size: <%= Profile.PreferredFontSizeForSomething %>;
  }
</style>
```

Please note however, that adding the `<style>` tag to the `<body>` is not allowed in HTML but works in all major browsers. It is allowed in HTML5, but only with the `scoped` attribute set (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751922/4830) for more info on that).